# ggplot2 polar plot axis label location

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, coordinate

This is just a extension for a old question
[ggplot2 polar plot arrows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10515703/ggplot2-polar-plot-arrows)
[image: Compass plot from MatLab]

You will find the x axis is out of the most_out circle.
In ggplot2, I use "panel.grid.major =  theme_line(colour = "black", size = 0.2, linetype=2)" to get the dashed circle, just as below:
[image: using GGplot2]
So my question is how to make the axis label (180, 135, 90, .....) outside of the circle, because the text are merge with the circular lines.

I try to use "hjust" or "vjust" to adjust the distance between text and axis. But it does not work.
So do you have some ideas about this problem?
Thanks first!!!!

Comment: Without code to reproduce, it's difficult to provide specific answers.

Comment: I think you should submit a bug report, I recently mentioned the same issue on the ggplot2-dev mailing list if you need a minimal example.

Comment: @boyang, why was my answer not acceptable?

Answer (score 2):

You have not provided code to reproduce the problem so this will be just a guess.

I've used whitespace, `\n` in particular, to move text "away" in the past. Perhaps a custom formatter might work here. Here is how you can write a [custom tick mark label formatter](http://wiki.stdout.org/rcookbook/Graphs/Axes%20(ggplot2)/#tick-mark-label-text-formatters).

If this fails, you can always hide the axis labels and paint them yourself using `geom_text` by adding another layer.

Hope this helps. @hadley's [book on ggplot2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387981403) is very good, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question while I was trying to fix a similar issue myself. One workaround is pretty much covered in the answer to this post: [Remove extra space and ring at the edge of a polar plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20808009/ggplot2-remove-extra-space-at-edge-of-polar-plot/20820592#20820592)

You would have to adjust the limits of the x scale to match your axis labels. You would also have to create a new scale bar corresponding to the radial length of your arrows (the 0-300 scale bar on the left side of your plot), since

```
axis.text = element_blank
```

takes the scale bar away as well.