# Remove extra space and ring at the edge of a polar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a polar plot in `ggplot2` that I am getting pretty close in finishing (fairly simple plot).  I have been able to get assistance in removing the rectangular boarder but not I need to remove the extra space between the last range contour and the ring around the plot that has the azimuth labels on it.  I would like for the bounds of this plot to be at 15,000... not 15,214 (I made that number up).  Thanks for any help.

The code to generate the plot is below:

```
# Load needed Libraries ---------------------------------------------------

library(ggplot2)

# Generate Fake Data ------------------------------------------------------

N    = 25
bng  = runif(N, min =  0, max = 360)
rng  = rlnorm(N, meanlog = 9, sdlog = 1)
det  = runif(N, min = 0, max = 1) >= 0.5

det  = factor(det)

data = data.frame(bng, rng, det)

# Generate the Plot -------------------------------------------------------

plot = ggplot(data) + theme_bw() +
  geom_point(aes(x = bng, y = rng, color = det), size = 5, alpha = 0.7) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,360), expand = c(0,0), breaks = seq(0,360-1, by=45)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,15000), breaks = seq(0,15000, by = 3000)) +
  coord_polar(theta = 'x', start = 0, direction = 1) +
  theme(legend.key = element_blank()) +
  theme(panel.border = element_blank(), axis.ticks = element_blank(), axis.text.y = element_blank()) +
  labs(x = '', y = '') +
  scale_color_manual(name = '', values = c('red', 'black'), breaks = c(FALSE, TRUE), labels = c('Not Detected', 'Detected'))
plot
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The extra space is generated by the outermost circle of a `panel.grid`. The grid is added by default in the `theme` you have used (and in most other `ggplot` themes; [default settings here](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/master/R/theme-defaults.r))

Thus, remove `panel.grid` in `theme`. You might then create an own grid, according to taste, using e.g. `geom_hline` and `geom_vline`. Here I used the breaks you had specified in `scale_x` and `_y` as intercepts. I picked line colour and size from default `panel.grid.major` in `theme_bw`.

```
ggplot(data = df) +
  geom_point(aes(x = bng, y = rng, color = det), size = 5, alpha = 0.7) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = seq(0, 15000, by = 3000), colour = "grey90", size = 0.2) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = seq(0, 360-1, by = 45), colour = "grey90", size = 0.2) +
  coord_polar(theta = 'x', start = 0, direction = 1) +
  labs(x = '', y = '') +
  scale_color_manual(name = '',
                     values = c('red', 'black'),
                     breaks = c(FALSE, TRUE),
                     labels = c('Not Detected', 'Detected')) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 360), expand = c(0, 0), breaks = seq(0, 360-1, by = 45)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 15000), breaks = seq(0, 15000, by = 3000)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.border = element_blank(),
        legend.key = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        panel.grid  = element_blank())
```

[image]