# How to remove coordinate in pie-chart generated by ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

Given this data:

```
abTcells    1456.74119
Macrophages 5656.38478
Monocytes   4415.69078
StemCells   1752.11026
Bcells  1869.37056
gdTCells    1511.35291
NKCells 1412.61504
DendriticCells  3326.87741
StromalCells    2008.20603
Neutrophils 12867.50224
```

This plot:
[image]

Is generated with the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)                  
df <- read.table("http://dpaste.com/1697602/plain/");
ggplot(df,aes(x=factor(1),y=V2,fill=V1))+
   geom_bar(width=1,stat="identity")+coord_polar(theta="y")
```

How can I remove the following:

1. Circular coordinate, e.g. (0, 10000, 20000,30000)
2. Y axis coordinate (e.g. 1)
3. White circle.

Comment: It's not about removing axis labels. But coordinates. So for example I do want to keep V2 as axis label, but I want to get rid of coordinate  (0, 10000, 20000,30000).

Comment: I hear you, but these labels make little sense on a polar plot. They can be removed by adding `+ labs(x="", y="")`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You may remove these elements by using relevant arguments in [**`theme`**](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/theme.html):

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(1), y = V2, fill = V1))+
  geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity") +
  coord_polar(theta = "y") +
  theme(axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        panel.grid  = element_blank())
```

[image]

After the entire grid is removed, you can manually add an own grid, using `geom_hline` and `geom_vline` (see [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20808009/ggplot2-remove-extra-space-at-edge-of-polar-plot/20820592#20820592)).

I recommend having a look in [**this tutorial**](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/).