# Remove outermost circle in grid using ggplot2, coord_polar

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a spider chart with ggplot2, using coordpolar.

I would like to remove the outermost circle in the grid on order to make the labels look nicer, any ideas?

I have used the mtcars dataset for reproducability. Here is what I have so far:

```
library(ggplot2) 
library(reshape2)
library(scales)

# Define a new coordinate system 
coord_radar <- function (theta = "x", start = 0, direction = 1) 
{
  theta <- match.arg(theta, c("x", "y"))
  r <- if (theta == "x") 
    "y"
  else "x"
  ggproto("CoordRadar", CoordPolar, theta = theta, r = r, start = start, 
          direction = sign(direction),
          is_linear = function(coord) TRUE)
}
is.linear.radar <- function(coord) TRUE 

# rescale all variables to lie between 0 and 1 
scaled <- as.data.frame(lapply(mtcars, ggplot2:::rescale01))

scaled$model <- rownames(mtcars)    # add model names as a variable 

as.data.frame(melt(scaled,id.vars="model")) -> mtcarsm

mtcarsm2 <- dplyr::filter(mtcarsm, model = model %in% c("Maserati Bora","Volvo 142E"))
my.color = c("red","darkgreen")

mtcarsm2$Make.color <-  ifelse(mtcarsm2$model=="Maserati Bora", "1",
                               ifelse(mtcarsm2$model=="Volvo 142E", "2",
                                      NA  ))

cols <- c("Maserati Bora" = "darkorange","Volvo 142E" = "blue")

library(scales)
library(ggthemes)

scaled <- as.data.frame(lapply(mtcars, ggplot2:::rescale01))
scaled$model <- rownames(mtcars)    # add model names as a variable
# melt the dataframe
mtcarsm <- reshape2::melt(scaled)
# plot it as using the polygon geometry in the polar coordinates
ggplot(mtcarsm2, aes(x = variable, y = value, fill=as.factor(model))) +
  geom_polygon(aes(group = model, color = model), fill = NA, size = 1) +
  coord_polar()+
  xlab("") + ylab("")+theme_minimal()+scale_colour_manual(
       values = c("Maserati Bora" = "darkorange","Volvo 142E" = "deepskyblue4"))+
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "lightblue",
                                        colour = "lightblue",
                                        size = 0.5, linetype = "solid"),
        panel.grid.major = element_line(size = 0.5, linetype = 'solid',
                                        colour = "white"), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_line(size = 0.25, linetype = 'solid',
                                        colour = "white"))
```

Resulting image

[image]

Comment: I _think_ [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20808009/ggplot2-remove-extra-space-at-edge-of-polar-plot/) may be relevant here.

Comment: Tried that Idea, could not make it work though..

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I´ll simplify the example

Comment: Why does Henrik's answer not work? I tried it and it looks fine.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Substituting your current `panel.grid.major` argument with `panel.grid = element_blank()` seems to work fine with your example.

```
ggplot(mtcarsm2, aes(x = variable, y = value, fill = as.factor(model))) +
    geom_polygon(aes(group = model, color = model), fill = NA, size = 1) +
    coord_polar() +
    xlab("") + 
    ylab("") +
    theme_minimal() + 
    scale_colour_manual(values = c("Maserati Bora" = "darkorange",
               "Volvo 142E" = "deepskyblue4")) + 
    theme(panel.background = element_rect(
         fill = "lightblue", colour = "lightblue", size = 0.5, 
         linetype = "solid"),
         panel.grid = element_blank(), 
         panel.grid.minor = element_line(
               size = 0.25, linetype = 'solid', colour = "white"))
```

Comment: When I run this code using the example data, it removes all lines, not just the outermost. I've been unable to achieve what the original poster wanted (remove just the redundant outer circle)