# How to remove whitespace when using coord_polar

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've had an issue as old as time when creating donut/pie charts in R (yes, I know...). The problem is that when using `coord_polar()`, white space is is created on the top and bottom of charts. Since I don't fully understand why this is the case I've been trying to remedy it with `theme()`  attributes to avail. Ultimately I'm looking for the ability of my plots to have this current whitespace be customizable to my choosing.

Here is a reproducible example that produces the following plot:

```
set.seed(42069)
data.frame("x" = sample(letters[1:5], 800, replace = T)) %>% 
  count(x) %>% 
  mutate("total" = sum(n),
         "percent" = n/total) %>% 
  
  ggplot(aes(x = 2, y = percent, fill = x))+
  coord_polar(theta = "y", start = 0)+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image]

Hard to see, but there is a white background on the top and the bottom (hence the spacing from the image seen in this chunk of text).

Comment: It probably a setting in the device. If you're using `ggsave()`, I think you could use `ggsave(..., bg = "black")` to set the device blackground to black.

Comment: Related? [Remove extra space and ring at the edge of a polar plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20808009/remove-extra-space-and-ring-at-the-edge-of-a-polar-plot)

Comment: @teunbrand is right. It's an artifact of the device's default background colour. Modifying the `dev.args` list changes the output!