# ggplot2: How to add closed (and filled) arrowheads to a polar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, polar-coordinates

Following this link:

[ggplot2 polar plot arrows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10515703/ggplot2-polar-plot-arrows/10517434#10517434)

I have been wondering how to get closed arrows on a polar plot in ggplot2.

Here is my code:

```
# make some data     
    polar <- structure(list(degree = c(120L, 30L, -120L, 60L, 150L, -90L, 
    -60L, 0L), value = c(0.5, 0.2, 0.2, 0.5, 0.4, 0.14, 0.5, 0.6)), .Names = c("degree", 
    "value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

    require(ggplot2)
    require(grid)

    base <- ggplot(polar, aes(x=degree, y=value, axis.x = NULL, axis.y = NULL))
    p <- base 
    p <- p + geom_segment(aes(y=0, xend=degree, yend=value)) # add the lines


    awid <- 1
    p <- p + geom_segment(aes(y=0, xend=degree, yend=value)) + geom_segment(aes(y=value-0.05,yend=value,x=degree-awid/value,xend=degree)) +  geom_segment(aes(y=value-0.05,yend=value,x=degree+awid/value,xend=degree))
    p
```

However, the arrowheads I get are open arrows, not closed. I was wondering how to replace the arrowheads with (essentially) filled triangles and still be in polar coordinates. Any suggestions?

Thanks a bunch in advance!

PS; updated to add issues with arrow. Here is the code I ran:

```
 require(ggplot2)
 require(grid)

 # Data     
 polar <- structure(list(degree = c(120L, 30L, -120L, 60L, 150L, -90L, -60L, 0L), 
                         value = c(0.5, 0.2, 0.2, 0.5, 0.4, 0.14, 0.5, 0.6)), 
                    .Names = c("degree", "value"), 
                    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

 ggplot(polar, aes(x=degree, y=value)) +
   geom_segment(aes(y=0, xend=degree, yend=value), arrow=arrow(type="closed")) +
   coord_polar()
```

And here is the plot I get:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `arrow()` function from `grid`, you only need one call to `geom_segment`.

```
 require(ggplot2)
 require(grid)

 # Data     
 polar <- structure(list(degree = c(120L, 30L, -120L, 60L, 150L, -90L, -60L, 0L), 
                         value = c(0.5, 0.2, 0.2, 0.5, 0.4, 0.14, 0.5, 0.6)), 
                    .Names = c("degree", "value"), 
                    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

 ggplot(polar, aes(x=degree, y=value)) +
   geom_segment(aes(y=0, xend=degree, yend=value), arrow=arrow(type="closed")) +
   coord_polar()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Could you provide me the complete code? I tried this earlier (and now) and the arrowheads all point westward.

Comment: I've added all the code I ran. All I really did was import your `polar` data and then run the `ggplot` code in my original answer.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this either.

Comment: Hmm. I ran the code in a clean session and got the same result. I'm running R 3.2.2, RStudio 0.99.484, and ggplot2 version 1.0.1.9003 on OSX 10.10.4.

Comment: I am also on R.3.2.2. My ggplot2 is at 1.0.1 also. \n packageVersion("grid")
[1] ‘3.2.2’
> packageVersion("ggplot2")
[1] ‘1.0.1’

Comment: Same versions here. I'm on Windows 10 though.

Comment: I am on linux, and I ran the code on a clean session also. I wonder what is different with eipi10's code. I don't use Rstudio but why should that have anytihing to do with it.

Comment: When you say you can't reproduce the plot I posted, what, specifically, happens when you run the code? Are you also getting all arrows pointing westward?

Comment: I have added both the code and the plot which gives issues. All done from a clean R session in a directory with ls() yielding character(0) at the start.

Comment: Yes, I'm getting the same things as OP. I'm using RStudio. Perhaps it works differently on the Quartz device? I don't know.